# windows microseconds calculation accuracy

Tags: .net, windows, datetime

I'm trying to convert DateTime to Julian date and reverse it under Windows 7.

```
    public static double ToJulianDate(this DateTime dt) {
        return dt.ToOADate() + 2415018.5;
    }
    public static DateTime Julian2DT(this double julian) {
        return DateTime.FromOADate(julian - 2415018.5);
    }
```

When I test these two functions like below

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff").Dump();
dt.ToJulianDate().Julian2DT().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff").Dump();
```

the reversed Julian date has always a slightly different value from the original DateTime value by hundreds microseconds.

Did I write a wrong code or there's some microseconds inaccuracy in windows time system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a natural result of the fact that the Julian date is represented as a `double`, which will always have limited accuracy. For example, the current value is about 2456348.78370906. That gives 7 significant digits before the decimal point - and a `double` is only accurate to "about" 15 decimal places. So we've got about 8 decimal digits of accuracy within the decimal part... which is meant to represent a day.

Now 1 day / 100000000 = 0.000864 seconds. So I'd only expect accuracy to just under a millisecond.

If you *don't* add the constant for a Julian date, things look rather rosier - at that point the current value is only about 41330, so there's more "room" within the value for precision in terms of the time of day. Basically, the larger floating point values get, the worse the precision is, in absolute terms. (The gap between adjacent values becomes larger.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A weird thing is DateTime.FromOADate(dt.ToOADate()) is exactly same with dt.ToJulianDate().Julian2DT() while different from the original dt.

Comment: DateTime.FromOADate(dt.ToOADate()) also has microseconds accuracy problem.